# Why won't my Eevee evolve with Leaf Stone in Pokemon Shield?

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield

Help. I would like a Leafeon for my play-through of Pokemon shield but my Eevee won't evolve when I try and use a leaf stone on it.
Everyone I see is saying that you evolve Eevee into Leafeon by using a leaf stone but it won't work.

Any ideas why this might be happening and if you know other ways of getting the Eeveelution then please say so.

Comment: Can you add a picture of what it shows when you try to use it?

Comment: It just says that it won't have any effect sorry i'm new I don't know how to add pictures :(

Comment: you can add a picture by using this icon when [edit] https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eu0w6.png

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! New users need a minimum of 10 or so reputation to add images to posts to prevent system abuse. They should now be able to add one (thanks to their well-received question), but it may not add much. If Wrigglenite has answered your question, please do mark it as The Answer with the checkmark just below their answer score at the left to help the community!

Comment: If all else fails, you apparently can find wild Leafeons in Lake of Outrage.

Comment: @Tsugihagi You can find all of the Eeveelutions in Lake of Outrage; just depends on the weather :)

Comment: You can also find regular Eevee on Route 4 (all times, low chance) or early sections of Wild Area (in certain weather) and evolve them yourself. If you don’t get the stones otherwise, they can often be found in the Lake of Outrage area.

Answer (score 24):

The Gigantamax Eevee you receive from owning Pokémon Let's Go Eevee can't evolve at all. The same holds true for the Gigantamax Pikachu from owning Let's Go Pikachu.

Comment: Also worth noting that this applies to the Gigantamax Meowth from Mystery Gift.